# Current function saves the last paragraph of a post. How to force a function to save the first paragrapgh block?

Tags: wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a function that takes suppose to take the first paragraph block of a post and save it to a custom field. However, the problem I have is that it saves that last paragraph of the post.

So if I have a post that has three paragraph blocks:

```
paragraph 1
paragraph 2
paragraph 3
```

It will save the last paragraph to a field.

Here's the function that I use:

```
function post_extra_save( $post_id, $post){
    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks =    parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
            if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/paragraph' ) { // name of block
                $media_video_url = strip_tags($block['innerHTML']);
                update_field('field_6074e55c6618f', $media_video_url, $post_id);
            };
    }
};
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_extra_save', 10, 2 );
```

How do I fix it to save the first paragraph block instead of the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `break` statement after `update_field`. check the below code.

```
function post_extra_save( $post_id, $post){
    if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
        $blocks =    parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
        foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {
            if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/paragraph' ) { // name of block
                $media_video_url = strip_tags($block['innerHTML']);
                update_field('field_6074e55c6618f', $media_video_url, $post_id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'post_extra_save', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the help.